# Pyautogui image recognition returns None no matter what I do

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I have been trying to get pyautogui to locate graphically a folder on my desktop but it fails no matter what I do:

This is my code (int_auto.py)

```
import pyautogui

button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('/Users/cadellteng/Desktop/Test-ground/randompy/pyxell2.png')
print(button)
```

I literally read through every SO thread I could find on this topic and some suggested that the photo needs to be lossless, so I used the cmd+shift+4 command on Mac to achieve this. A screenshot of my desktop and the reference image I used is attached here.

[image: desktop_image]
Note: This photo was converted to jpg because SO only allows photos up to 2MiB to be uploaded

[image: pyautogui reference image]

Other things I tried are:
1. using locateAllOnScreen
2. grayscale = True
3. uninstall pyautogui and reinstalling pyautogui

But no matter what I did, I couldn't seems to be able to get the outcome I want. If it helps, I use a double screen and my code editor (VS Code) is on the secondary screen. What you see here as my desktop is my primary screen.

When the program is running nothing is blocking the folder.

There is also a warning on my terminal which I'm not sure if it's going to be useful:

```
/Users/cadellteng/Desktop/Test-ground/randompy/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rubicon/objc/ctypes_patch.py:21: 
UserWarning: rubicon.objc.ctypes_patch has only been tested with Python 3.4 through 3.7.
You are using Python 3.8.2. Most likely things will work properly, but you may experience crashes if Python's internals have changed significantly. warnings.warn(
```

Do let me know if you require additional information.

EDIT June 01, 2020: So I thought that maybe pyautogui was not able to detect the folder because there are multiple folders and they all look the same and was not able to detect it. So I got this image off the web and tried to search it with it opened on my desktop with nothing else blocking it. But even then it was not able to find it.
[image: robot.png]

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong here but with each try, I am becoming more convinced that this API is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the picture might be a problem. When I use locateOnScreen to find an element in a browser and zoom out by, for example, 10%, then it will not locate it on screen even if is almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Macbook so I think its because of the pixel density of the screen and the resolution pyautogui detects. You can check by:
image = pyautogui.LocateCenterOnScreen(‘image.png’)
print(image)
If you see coordinates above 2000 its probably because of the resolution. I suggest a workaround if you want to click the image like:
pyautogui.click(image.x/2, image.y/2, clicks=1, interval=10, button=‘left’) also try cropping the images as small as possible!